# How to continue collecting cubes in FEZ after 32-cube door and reboot?

Tags: fez

I have collected 32 cubes in FEZ and get into super-high-resolution word, and... "dos-reboot" like at the begining, and got something, which looks like an final.

Now I would like to continue exploration, but I can't continue... the continue is gray - I can't select it.

It looks like the only thing I can do is to start a new game and repeat everything what I have done.
Is there other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have chosen "start a new game+" instead of continue, and, after climbing up and viewing 64-cube  disintegration scene, I started from my previous point, with same map I got before and with 32 cubes in a pocket.